# IllegalStateException androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment$4 in onChanged

Tags: android, kotlin, android-dialogfragment

I'm facing a weird crash  , I don’t know how can I track this crash.

```
DialogFragment can not be attached to a container view

java.lang.IllegalStateException: DialogFragment can not be attached to a container view
at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment$4.onChanged(DialogFragment.java:151)
at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment$4.onChanged(DialogFragment.java:144)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:133)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:151)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:309)
at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3115)
at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.performCreateView(DialogFragment.java:510)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:524)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1424)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2968)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3129)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:552)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1890)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1814)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1751)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

BaseDialogFragment

```
open class BaseDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

override fun getTheme(): Int = R.style.NoMarginsDialog

private fun setupWidthToMatchParent() {
    dialog?.window?.setLayout(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    setupWidthToMatchParent()
}   }
```

I am using this Abstract class to not repeat init code for ViewModel & onViewCreated & binding

```
abstract class AbstractDialogFragment<VBinding : ViewBinding, ViewModel : BaseViewModel> :
BaseDialogFragment() {


protected lateinit var viewModel: ViewModel
protected abstract fun getVModel(): Class<ViewModel>

protected lateinit var binding: VBinding
protected abstract fun getViewBinding(): VBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    init()
    observeData()
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    dialog?.window?.setLayout(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    )
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    setUpViews()
}

open fun setUpViews() {}

open fun observeData() {}
  
 

private fun init() {
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[getVModel()]
    binding = getViewBinding()
} }
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="NoMarginsDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>
```

these are all my classes
this crash mostly comes from android version 8.1.0
I tried running the app with this version, but i didn’t face it 
if anyone has an idea for this crash, I will be thank

Answer (score 2):

I had the same crash in Crashlytics.
And I've solved this by detaching of existing view binding of a fragment from it's previous parent.

[DialogFragment](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/fragment/fragment/src/main/java/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment.java#390)'s source code tells that such exception is being thrown if fragment's view already has a parent:

```
private Observer<LifecycleOwner> mObserver = new Observer<LifecycleOwner>() {
    @SuppressLint("SyntheticAccessor")
    @Override
    public void onChanged(LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner) {
        if (lifecycleOwner != null && mShowsDialog) {
            View view = requireView();
            if (view.getParent() != null) {    <----------- THIS IS THE KEY
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "DialogFragment can not be attached to a container view");
            }
            if (mDialog != null) {
                if (FragmentManager.isLoggingEnabled(Log.DEBUG)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "DialogFragment " + this + " setting the content view on "
                        + mDialog);
                }
                mDialog.setContentView(view);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**onChanged()** method of **mObserver** is being called in case of view re-creation, that is seen from [Fragment](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/fragment/fragment/src/main/java/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.java#3097)'s source code.

```
void performCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
        @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mChildFragmentManager.noteStateNotSaved();
    mPerformedCreateView = true;
    mViewLifecycleOwner = new FragmentViewLifecycleOwner(this, getViewModelStore());    <----------- NEW OWNER IS CREATED
    mView = onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);    <----------- VIEW CREATION/RE-CREATION
    if (mView != null) {
        // Initialize the view lifecycle
        mViewLifecycleOwner.initialize();
        // Tell the fragment's new view about it before we tell anyone listening
        // to mViewLifecycleOwnerLiveData and before onViewCreated, so that calls to
        // ViewTree get() methods return something meaningful
        ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(mView, mViewLifecycleOwner);
        ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner.set(mView, mViewLifecycleOwner);
        ViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner.set(mView, mViewLifecycleOwner);
        // Then inform any Observers of the new LifecycleOwner
        mViewLifecycleOwnerLiveData.setValue(mViewLifecycleOwner);    <----------- SET NEW OWNER, NOTIFY OBSERVERS
    } else {
        if (mViewLifecycleOwner.isInitialized()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Called getViewLifecycleOwner() but "
                    + "onCreateView() returned null");
        }
        mViewLifecycleOwner = null;
    }
}
```

In **onCreateView()** method of your fragment **binding.root** object is being returned. Need to say that **binding** survives between view re-creations. Thus, first time fragment is created, **binding.root** doesn't have a parent, but after view re-creation it is still being bound to previous parent.

Thereofore, the idea is to unbind **binding.root** from previous parent (if there) during view re-creation:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, parent: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return binding.root.let {
        if (it.parent != null) {
            (it.parent as ViewGroup).removeView(it)
        }
        it
    }
}
```